# Confusion between PK and FK table design

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a `person` table and a `score` table. The `Person` table basically stores a person's information while `score` table stores what kind of score a person has. I set the FK constraint in `score` table to `ON DELETE: CASCADE`

```
person
- id
- name
- scored_id (FK)

score
- id (PK)
- bmi
- weight
```

So, in the table setting `score.id` is linked with person's `scored_id`. That being said when I delete a record in `score`, a person  will get deleted as well. But why when I delete a record in `person`, the record of his in score is not deleted?

Comment: Can you include the script you use to create these tables

Comment: Unless you go for circular dependencies with your foreign keys then this is generally the nature of the beast - a one way dependancy

Comment: it seems that you've improperly set your foreign keys.Post the script as          @NigelRen says.

Comment: @NigelRen what's that for? isn't it clear enough my table above shows the relationship?

Comment: @Kiwagi really? what is wrong here? is my table structure correct?

Comment: The key constraint, as it is works fine - one way. Using a circular reference on these two tables will not work though

Comment: @RamRaider should I put a key in score table? like Lalmani Dewangan's answer, do you think my structure is wrong? let's not talk bout keys first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea how you might structure the tables and use a foreign key which will delete records from the score table if/when a user from the person table is deleted. The `score` table should have a reference to the user - `pid` which is used as the foreign key dependancy. It makes sense to me that the score is dependant upon the user so no user, no score.

```
create table `person` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(50) null default null,
    primary key (`id`)
)
collate='latin1_swedish_ci'
engine=innodb
auto_increment=4;


mysql> describe person;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+




create table `score` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `bmi` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    `weight` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    `pid` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`),
    index `pid` (`pid`),
    constraint `fk_sc_pid` foreign key (`pid`) references `person` (`id`) on update cascade on delete cascade
)
collate='latin1_swedish_ci'
engine=innodb
auto_increment=4;



mysql> describe score;
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bmi    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| weight | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| pid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+





mysql> select * from person;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | bob  |
|  2 | rita |
|  3 | sue  |
+----+------+


mysql> select * from score;
+----+-----+--------+-----+
| id | bmi | weight | pid |
+----+-----+--------+-----+
|  1 |  34 |     34 |   1 |
|  2 |  56 |     41 |   2 |
|  3 |  56 |     77 |   3 |
+----+-----+--------+-----+



mysql> delete from person where id=3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

/* delete a user, the score disappears too which makes sense */

mysql> select * from score;
+----+-----+--------+-----+
| id | bmi | weight | pid |
+----+-----+--------+-----+
|  1 |  34 |     34 |   1 |
|  2 |  56 |     41 |   2 |
+----+-----+--------+-----+
```

Comment: yes, make sense, my structure is wrong at the first place

Comment: generally database design is rarely "spot on" at the first attempt- little tweaks here and there as you get a clearer idea of what is to happen and how it is to operate etc. Hope the above and others notes / advice have helped a little.

Comment: Plus ten from me. @Madeline Ries, worth looking at my answer as I think it helpfully supplements RamRaiders with a narrative explanation. Goodluck with your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is semantic understanding of the task, rather than syntax. Intuitively your relation looks wrong. It is unlikely, that a particular score, say 75kg and bmi of 20 will need to have a many relations link to people with the same score. This would be arbitary. More likely, your want, a person to have different scores over time, then when you delete a person, you want their associated values deleted. So table relation should be:

```
person
- id (Primary Key)
- name

score
- id (Primary Key)
- bmi
- weight
- scoreDate
- personID (Foreign Key to person)
```

A score date would be a helpful addition.

This structure will allow a person to have a history of many score and see the fluctuation of their weight and body mass index over time. A semantically helpful task that resonates with reality, and therefore follows the notions of entity analysis and table structures following the real world application.

[Helpful discussion of ERD and table structure levels and relations](http://www.siue.edu/~dbock/cmis450/3-ermodel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In you tables, "person" table is having reference(FK) of "score" table so when you delete a record in "score" table mysql search related record in "users" table to delete.

but "score" table dose not have any reference(FK) of "person" table.

You can try below table structure if you want to delete score record when person record will be delete but person record will be still safe if score record will be delete

```
person
- id (PK)
- name

score
- id (PK)
- person_id (FK)
- bmi
- weight
```